# Not working with Edit Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm Creating an Edit button that will edit my data in my row. the problem is if I click multiple edit button it doesn't comply. 
It only complies when I click 1 edit button.

HERE IS MY EXAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/te2wF/31/

**HERES MY CODE**

```
function editRow(t)
{
        var i = t.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

        if (  table.rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value =="Edit")
        {
            var name = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
            var age = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            var gender = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            var tname = table.rows[i].cells[0];
            var tage = table.rows[i].cells[1];
            var tgender = table.rows[i].cells[2];

            tname.innerHTML = "";
            var textname = document.createElement("input");
            textname.id = "textname";
            tname.appendChild(textname);

            tage.innerHTML = "";
            var textage = document.createElement("input");
            textage.id = "textage";
            tage.appendChild(textage);
            tgender.innerHTML = "";
            var textgender = document.createElement("select");
            textgender.id = "textgender";
            tgender.appendChild(textgender);

            document.getElementById('textname').focus();
            document.getElementById("uid").innerHTML = i;
            document.getElementById("textname").value = name;
            document.getElementById("textage").value = age;
             textgender.options.add(Option(gender));

            if(gender == "Male")    textgender.options.add(new Option("Female"));
            else                    textgender.options.add(new Option("Male"));


            table.rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value="Save"
            document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("age").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("gender").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("insert").disabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            update(document.getElementById('uid').innerHTML);
            table.rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value="Edit"
            document.getElementById("insert").disabled = false;

        }
    }
```

Thank you for helping.....

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're assigning the same id to multiple elements.  That could be creating the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you should change:
`textgender.options.add(Option(gender));`
to
`textgender.options.add(new Option(gender));`

But more to the point on the edit button:

You're attempting to access the editable inputs on your table by id - but when you create a second set of textname and textage inputs, the id's are the same as the other row that you're editing.  You either need to create unique id's on these elements (perhaps by appending the row number to the id), or you need to set it up so that you can only edit one row at a time (disable and grey the other rows when you're editing one)

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm quite confused about appending the row number to the id? what do you mean by that? thank you again for responding

Comment: It's just a trick to make sure that the textname input element on, say, row 3 has a different id than the textname input element on, say, row 5.  so, `textname.id = "textname"+i` will do.  You also shouldn't be using the 'uid' tagged element as a global - instead pull the rowID for the update from the `this` element when you click on "Save" just as when you click on the Edit button.  I'd recommend fiddling about with the javascript debugger in Chrome to help - it's invaluable!

Comment: I've tried your suggestion using textname.id = "textname"+i but it didn't work because when I clicked the edit button nothing happens. By the way I'm using FF. thank you again Kevin for your response

Comment: yup - you've got to change other things in your logic to make it work, too (for example you then need to modify anything that does getElementByID("textname") - but for a simple example like this, it's probably easier for you to look at it in action.  I haven't used FF in a year - but Chrome is a quick download, and the developer tools are already integrated in - so you can not only interactively debug the app, but you can also inspect and edit DOM elements on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Please, when using jsfiddle, please keep javascript on javascript tab and html on html tab to make it easier and faster to help you.

I believe you should adjust 2 places on your code:

**First**

```
document.getElementById('textname').focus();
document.getElementById("uid").innerHTML = i;
document.getElementById("textname").value = name;
document.getElementById("textage").value = age;
textgender.options.add(Option(gender));
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('textname').focus();
document.getElementById("uid").innerHTML = i;
document.getElementById("textname").value = name;
document.getElementById("textage").value = age;
textgender.options.add(new Option(gender));
```

**Second:**

```
        else
        {
            update(document.getElementById('uid').innerHTML);
            table.rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value="Edit"
            document.getElementById("insert").disabled = false;

        }
```

should be:

```
        else
        {
            update(document.getElementById('uid').innerHTML);
            table.rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value="Edit"
            document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("age").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("gender").disabled = false;                
            document.getElementById("insert").disabled = false;

        }
```

try here http://jsfiddle.net/te2wF/31/